# Does $ \int _1^{\infty }\frac{\sinh (a \log (x))}{\sqrt{x}} $ converge or diverge?

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

How do I find out if $ \int_1^{\infty } \sinh (a \log x) /\sqrt x \, dx $ diverges or converges? **Wolfram** says that:
$$\begin{align} \int_1^{\infty } \frac{\sinh (a \log x)}{\sqrt{x}} \, dx &= \frac{4 a}{1-4 a^2} \\ 
\int_1^k \frac{\sinh (a \log x)}{\sqrt{x}} \, dx &= \frac{4 a-2 \sqrt{k} \bigl(2 a \cosh (a \log k)-\sinh (a \log k) \bigr)}{1-4 a^2} \end{align}$$

If it is correct, then:
$$ \lim _{k\to \infty } \left( \vphantom{A^{B^C}} 2 \sqrt{k} \bigl[2 a \cosh (a \log k)-\sinh (a \log k ) \bigr]\right)=0 $$

But numeric calculations says that $ 2 \sqrt{k} \bigl(2 a \cosh (a \log k)-\sinh (a \log k) \bigr) $ for any $ a $ will be $ \mp \infty $.

So what answer is correct?

Comment: The Wolfram result for the improper integral makes no sense when $a\gt1/2$, since the integrand $\sinh(a\log x)/\sqrt x$ is non-negative for $x\ge1$.

Answer (score 1):

Well we have

$$\sinh(a\log x) = \frac{x^a-x^{-a}}{2}$$

Thus the integral reduces to

$$\int_1^\infty \frac{x^a-x^{-a}}{2\sqrt{x}}dx$$

and this integral diverges for any $a\neq 0$ since would need simultaneously that $\frac{1}{2} < a < - \frac{1}{2}$